# My progressbar is causing my activity to crash

Tags: android

I am making an Android messaging application, and whenever someone does something like update their user profile, create an account, log in to their account, etc, it will show a custom progress bar layout that I have created.

To show that progress bar, I have used the `include` tag in my layouts, and set the visibility of that in `onCompleteListeners` and such.

However, in debug mode, I have seen that it is setting the progress bar to null and destroys all the objects in that activity, like the email, username, whatever they were updating in that activity.

This is apparently crashing the app, what could be causing this peculiar issue?

Here is my signup activity code:

```
private TextInputEditText etEmail, etName;
private String email, name;

private ImageView ivProfile;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private StorageReference fileStorage;
private Uri localFileUri, serverFileUri;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private View progressBar;

// Text is changed for confirm dialog
private Boolean textChanged = false;

@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
    ivProfile = findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);

    fileStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    setTitle("Profile");
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    if (firebaseUser!=null)
    {
        etName.setText(firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
        etEmail.setText(firebaseUser.getEmail());
        serverFileUri = firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl();

        if (serverFileUri!=null)
        {
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(serverFileUri)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile)
                    .error(R.drawable.default_profile)
                    .into(ivProfile);
        }
    }

    etName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textChanged = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });




}

// Logout button
public void btnLogoutClick(View view)
{

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth.signOut();
    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    finish();
}


// Save changes button
public void btnSaveClick(View view)
{
    if (textChanged)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Save changes")
                .setMessage("Please confirm that you want to apply these changes to your profile.")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                        {
                            etName.setError(getString(R.string.enter_name));
                        } else {
                            if (localFileUri!=null){
                                updateNameAndPhoto();
                            } else {
                                updateOnlyName();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        finish();
                    }
                })

                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_save_primarycolor)
                .show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.nothing_to_save, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

}


// Changing profile image
public void changeImage(View view)
{

    if (serverFileUri==null)
    {
        pickImage();
    }
    else
    {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_picture, popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                if (id==R.id.mnuChangePic)
                {
                    pickImage();
                }
                else if (id==R.id.mnuRemovePic)
                {
                    removePhoto();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }

}


// Method to change image
private void pickImage()
{



    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
    }
    else
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 102);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            textChanged = true;
            localFileUri = data.getData();
            ivProfile.setImageURI(localFileUri);
        }

    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode==102)
    {
        if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_required, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}


// Method to remove image
private void removePhoto()
{

    textChanged = true;

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    UserProfileChangeRequest request = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName(etName.getText().toString().trim())
            .setPhotoUri(null)
            .build();

    firebaseUser.updateProfile(request).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String userID = firebaseUser.getUid();
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(NodeNames.USERS);

                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put(NodeNames.PHOTO, "");

                databaseReference.child(userID).setValue(hashMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, R.string.photo_removed_successfully, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,
                        getString(R.string.failed_to_update_profile, task.getException()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}


// Method that updates the name and the profile photo of the user
private void updateNameAndPhoto()
{
   final String strFileName= firebaseUser.getUid() + ".jpg";

    final  StorageReference fileRef = fileStorage.child("images/"+ strFileName);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fileRef.putFile(localFileUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        serverFileUri = uri;

                        UserProfileChangeRequest request = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(etName.getText().toString().trim())
                                .setPhotoUri(serverFileUri)
                                .build();

                        firebaseUser.updateProfile(request).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    String userID = firebaseUser.getUid();
                                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(NodeNames.USERS);

                                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

                                    hashMap.put(NodeNames.NAME, etName.getText().toString().trim());
                                    hashMap.put(NodeNames.PHOTO, strFileName);

                                    databaseReference.child(userID).setValue(hashMap)
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                    finish();
                                                }
                                            });


                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,
                                            getString(R.string.failed_to_update_profile, task.getException()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }}});

}

// Method that updates only the username of the user
private void updateOnlyName()
{

    // textChanged = true;

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    UserProfileChangeRequest request = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName(etName.getText().toString().trim())
            .build();

    firebaseUser.updateProfile(request).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(NodeNames.USERS);

                HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

                hashMap.put(NodeNames.NAME, etName.getText().toString().trim());

                databaseReference.child(userId).setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        finish();

                    }
                });


            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,
                        getString(R.string.failed_to_update_profile, task.getException()) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}


// Change password button
public void btnChangePasswordClick(View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ChangePasswordActivity.class));
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // super.onBackPressed();
    if (textChanged)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Save changes")
                .setMessage("You have made changes to your profile. Would you like to save them?")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                        {
                            etName.setError(getString(R.string.enter_name));
                        } else {
                            if (localFileUri!=null){
                                updateNameAndPhoto();
                            } else {
                                updateOnlyName();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        finish();
                    }
                })

                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_save_primarycolor)
                .show();
    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm fairly new to Android Studio and coding with Java, be easy on me :v

Comment: cany post the stack trace error?

Comment: Please check the LogCat and add the info to your question.

Comment: Check out my answer and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share enough details, but from what I can see, you're most likely calling one of your functions before your progressView initialization.

Ensure that none of the functions that reference your progressBar come before the line:

```
private View progressBar
```

For example, the implementation below would make your app crash:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    removePhoto() // a method that references progressBar
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar); // progressBar initialization
```

> In summary, you should initialize your progressBar before using it. If
> this is not done, you'll end up with a NullPointerException and your
> app would crash.

You might also want to do the following:

- Change the progressBar type from `View` to `ProgressBar`
- Check if the id of the progressBar from the XML file is actually **progressBar**.
- Clean your project (Build > Clean Project) and run again.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This will not cause the crash the view is only changing their visibility from progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); to progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: @Jorgesys I have edited my answer. I think OP is calling one of the methods referencing progressBar before initializing the progressbar itself.

Comment: Cleaning the project worked. It is now saving the user data to Firebase. Now it is crashing after showing the splash screen (??) but you do not have to help me with that part.

Comment: Alright, this means there's probably another error somewhere. Kindly upvote and accept my answer if it helped you. Cheers!